ogenで同一名称のヘッダが複数ある場合に取得したい
ogenを使ってOpenAPIのAPIサーバを作成しているのですが、
同一名称のヘッダーが2つ以上あった時に両方の値を取得することはできますでしょうか。
以下の２通りで試しましたが、1つしか取得できませんでした。
explodeフラグも試しましたが、1つしか取得できませんでした。
何か方法があればご教授いただきたくよろしくお願いいたします。
parameters:
        - name: X-Subject
          in: header
          schema:
            type: string


parameters:
        - name: X-Subject
          in: header
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string

